# Cosider the stability of the equilibrium point of the system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

> Consider the stability of the equilibrium point of the system
> $$
> \dot{x}=\mathrm{e}^{x+y}-\sqrt{1+2x}
> $$
> $$
> \dot{y}=\sin(xy)+\ln(1+2x)
> $$

The equilibrium of the system is $(0,0)$. My problem is to determine whether it is Lyapunov stable/asymptotically stable or not. I am currently working on using contraction. To be more precise, if we can prove for some positive initial value, $x(t), y(t)$ are all positive, then $\dot{y}$ must have a positive lower bound, but I cannot write a clear proof. If my way is wrong, please suggest your method. By the way, is there any more generalized criterion suitable for the problem?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you looked at the eigenvalues of the linearised system?

Comment: $\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}$. What can we know from that? I just learned al ittle stability theory.

Comment: The strictly positive eigenvalue tells you that the origin is unstable.

Comment: Could you tell me where can I find the proof of the theorem? Thanks!

Comment: It is usually referred to a Lyapunov's theorem. I need to check my library to see if I can find a specific reference. Basically if the linearisation has no zero eigenvalues then the local stability is determined by the real parts of the eigenvalues in the expected way.

Comment: My book is old, but Vidyasagar's "Nonlinear systems analysis", Theorem 41 (odd numbering system) in Section 5.4 is an example that related to instability. But I would guess that any control book that deals with Lyapunov's methods will have some version thereof.

Comment: You can also see Chapter 3 of Khalil's book or his lecture slides here:https://www.egr.msu.edu/~khalil/NonlinearControl/Slides-Full/Lect_4.pdf